# HTTP request inside another request in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I need to perform an HTTP request inside another request, which as much as I understand needs to be synchronous.
In this case, I fetch an array of "posts" and getting the information about them.
Here's the code, to help you understand the situation better:

```
// getPosts()
...
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if response != nil {
        let dataDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as [NSDictionary]     
        for postDic: NSDictionary in dataDictionary {
           let post = Post(postId: postDic["post_id"] as String)

           post.likes = postDic["likes"] as String
           post.views = postDic["views"] as String

           self.getCommentCountForPostID(post.postId, completion: { (count) -> Void in
               post.comments = count
           })

           ...
           self.posts.addObject(post)
        }
        // reloading table view etc
    }
})
task.resume()
```

And this is the function `getCommentCountForPostID`:

```
func getCommentCountForPostID(postID: String, completion: ((count : String?) -> ())) {
    ...
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if response != nil {
            let resultCount: NSString! = NSString(bytes: data.bytes, length: data.length, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
            print(resultCount)

            completion(count: resultCount)
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

The problem is that the `getCommentCountForPostID` function dispatches asynchronously while the `for` loop runs forward. I need the function to first comment request to finish and only then continue with the execution of `getPosts()`. I've tried many combinations of wrapping different parts in code with `dispatch_sync()` but with no success.
How can I achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Did you already tried to use dispatch_semaphore? If not, give it a try

Comment: To solve this problem the best fit NSURLConnection. It uses NSOperations, which are very easy to solve this problem (e.g. with using a dependencies).

Comment: @HorseT Can you show me an example of its usage? I looked it up but couldn't quite understand how to use it in my case

Comment: @Mozilla Can you please show me an example? I've tried to mess around with it a little bit too but didn't really know what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion for your purpose.

load first post -> process it -> load next -> finish when all post were loaded.

i created helper method called 'loopAndLoad' which takes your data array as param, and index of current item to process

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if response != nil {
                let dataDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as [NSDictionary]
                self.loopAndLoad(0, dataDictionary);
            }
        })
        task.resume()



    func loopAndLoad( index: Int, dataArray: Array<NSDictionary>)
    {
        let postDic = dataArray[index]
        let post = Post(postId: postDic["post_id"] as String)

        post.likes = postDic["likes"] as String
        post.views = postDic["views"] as String

        self.getCommentCountForPostID(post.postId, completion: { (count) -> Void in
            post.comments = count
            self.posts.addObject(post)
            if (++index < dataArray.count)
            {
                self.loopAndLoad(index, dataArray)
            }
            else
            {
                /// end of loop
            }
        })
    }


    func getCommentCountForPostID(postID: String, completion: ((count : String?) -> ())) {
        ...
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if response != nil {
                let resultCount: NSString! = NSString(bytes: data.bytes, length: data.length, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                print(resultCount)

                completion(count: resultCount)
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```